# Storing keys and values in a list like a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

How can I make a list similar to dictionary ?
When I have a text below

> The scientists hope facial recognition may help with their
>   understanding of neurodegenerative diseases.

I would like to make a distribution list. For example in this case, every each words appear once, then I am thinking the list should be

```
[(('the'), 1),
(('scientists'), 1), 
(('hope'), 1),........]
```

I also suppose to make distribution graph based on those list.
Is there any other better way in this case?
It would be really appreciated if you explained in detail.

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary? If you do you can convert to a list with `list(dict.items())`.

Comment: @internet_user: Dictionaries don't preserve order, which could be a very good reason not to do that.

Comment: @martineau if that's important you can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: @Mark: True, of course...but that's not what internet_user suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would want to use a list here, a dictionary would be easier to make and access. Even better, a `collections.Counter` could be built directly from a list of words like so:

```
from collections import Counter

words = ["the", "scientists", ...]

word_counter = Counter(words) # a subclass of dict

# word_list = list(word_counter.items()) # this would convert it to a list of tuples
```

If you need to preserve order, you could use a dictionary of indices into the list:

```
words = ["the", "scientists", ...]

counts = []
indices = {}
for word in words:
  if word in indices:
    counts[word][1] += 1
  else:
    indices[word] = len(counts)
    counts.append([word, 1])
```

You could also just search the list for the right index, but this is faster.